# JS – Object literal converted to number?

Tags: javascript, syntax

While playing around in Chrome's dev console, I noticed something that I don't understand:

- `({})+""` evaluates to `"[object Object]"`, as I expected
- `{}+""` evaluates to `0` (number)

Replacing `{}` with `{foo:"bar"}` in either expression doesn't change the result, so it does seem to be being parsed as an object literal. Replacing `""` with `"42"` yields `42`, and replacing it with `"foo"` yields `NaN`.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *context* of the grammar changes.

`({})` is an object literal expression evaluating to a new object so the code is effectively `anObject+""`. The parenthesis are defining here as they cause the code to be parsed as "(..some expression..)".

`{}+""` is parsed as `{};+""` since the {} are parsed as an empty block (as opposed to an object literal). This makes the code equivalent to `+""` which yields 0.

`{foo:"bar"}` is parsed as block, with a *label* ("foo") to the singular expression "bar". There is no object literal.

Some (useful) ways where `{..}` will be parsed as an object literal expression:

```
z = {..}
({..})
f({..})
return {..}
```

Comment: Ah, of course. I didn't even know that JS had labels :D